# Angular JS Nested Children Based on ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a 'tree' navigation and I'm having a problem with nesting the child items, the  server sending me JSON data that looks like this:

**JSON**:

```
0: {id:5, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder}
1: {id:6, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder}
2: {id:7, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder}
3: {id:8, parentid:7, text:PlaceHolder}
4: {id:9, parentid:7, text:PlaceHolder}
5: {id:10, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder}
6: {id:11, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder}
7: {id:12, parentid:7, text:PlaceHolder}
8: {id:15, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder}
9: {id:16, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder}
10: {id:17, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder}
11: {id:18, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder}
12: {id:19, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder}
13: {id:20, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder}
14: {id:21, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder}
15: {id:23, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder}
```

Notice the 'parentid'. "0" means the item is a top level parent. And for example, if the 'parentid' is 7 then it would be a child of 'id' 7.

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="link in links"><a href="#/page/{[{link.id}]}">{[{link.text}]}</li>
```

**JS:**

```
var Site = angular.module('Site', []);

Site.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page/:slug', {templateUrl: 'partials/page.html', controller: 'RouteController'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/page/home'});
});

function AppController ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
  /* Load pages on startup
  $http.get('pages.json').success(function (data) {
    $rootScope.pages = data;
  }); */
  // Load navigation on startup
  $http.get('/university/list').success(function (data) {
    $rootScope.links = data;

  });
  // Set the slug for menu active class
  $scope.$on('routeLoaded', function (event, args) {
    $scope.slug = args.slug;
  });
}

function RouteController ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
  // Getting the slug from $routeParams
  var slug = $routeParams.slug;

  $scope.$emit('routeLoaded', {slug: slug});
  $scope.page = $rootScope.pages[slug];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zzal/qdvuN/10/  ... from your question on the IRC channel here's the way to setup the menu:

Try to get the JSON responses in an array:

```
var PlaceHolder = "PlaceHolder";
var myArr =
[{id:5, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:6, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:7, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:8, parentid:7, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:9, parentid:7, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:10, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:11, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:12, parentid:7, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:15, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:16, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:17, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:18, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:19, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:20, parentid:0, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:21, parentid:15, text:PlaceHolder},
 {id:23, parentid:5, text:PlaceHolder}];
```

Now, create the nested array to hold your "children" objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
  myArr[i].children = [];
  for (var q = 0; q < myArr.length; q++){
    if (myArr[i].id == myArr[q].parentid){
      // if want to keep the parentid key
      //var temp = {id:myArr[q].id,parentid:myArr[q],text:myArr[q].text}
      var temp = {id:myArr[q].id,text:myArr[q].text};
      myArr[i].children.push(temp);
    };
  };  
};
```

Now your array `myArr` should end up with a new key array `children` with the layout needed to follow the example.